# WPF DataGrid issue: why the data output twice?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I am a newbie for the WPF programming. I wrote a simple sample about the WPF DataGrid control and use the MVVM pattern. What I want to do is display the data in the DataGrid control. However, the data always repeated in the datagrid. The output just like the picture below:
[image]

the code snippets:

```
// Model: 
Public class Machine
{
    Private string _uuid;
    public string UUID {get{ return _uuid; } set{ _uuid = value; }}
    public Targets(string uuid)
    {
         UUID = uuid;
    }
 }


// ViewModel:
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Machine> _machine = new ObservableCollection<Machine>();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _machine.Add(new Machine("1234"));
    }
    public ObservableCollection< Machine > Machines
    {
        get { return _machine; }
    }
}

// XAML:
<DataGrid Name="datagGrid1" Margin="2,2,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Width="120"
                           Binding="{Binding UUID}"
                       Header="UUID-S" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: It'd help if you show your actual code (the above won't compile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [`AutoGenerateColumns="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) in the XAML.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="datagGrid1" Margin="2,2,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- ...
```